# react native spinner doesn't display on bottom

Tags: react-native

So I got this piece of code, and I want to display the Spinner on the bottom of the screen, just right after the FlatList, but when the function displaySpinner is called nothing displays after the flatlist. I've tried many things like putting trying to display the Spinner on the top of the view and then give it a Top but it's not what I'm looking for. 
By the way I'm new in the programming world and more on React Native so I hope everything makes sense to understand my problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment';
import Card from './Card';
import CardSection from './CardSection';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

class ArticleList extends Component {
    state = { articles: [],
        refreshing: false,
        isLoading: false,

    };

    componentWillMount() {
        this.loadArticles();
    }

    currentOffset = 0;



   reloadContent() {
    this.setState({

        isLoading: true
    });
        this.currentOffset += 20;
        console.log(this.currentOffset);
        this.loadArticles(); 
    }

    loadArticles = () => {
        const { articles } = this.state;


        console.log(this.currentOffset);

        axios.get(`https://sportsoftheday.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20&offset=${this.currentOffset}`)
            .then(res =>
                this.setState({
                    articles: this.currentOffset === 0 ? res.data : [...articles, ...res.data],
                    isLoading: false,
                }))
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    };
    displaySpinner() {
        if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
            return <Spinner size='large' />;
        }
    }

    //Apply removeClippedSubviews for eliminating useless data on the screen


    render() {
        const { articles } = this.state;

        this.date = this.date;
        this.fimg_url = this.fimg_url;

        return (
<View>

                <FlatList
                    data={articles}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (


                        <Card>

                            <CardSection>

                                <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>

                                    <Image
                                        style={styles.thumbnailStyle}
                                        source={{
                                            uri: item.fimg_url,
                                            cache: 'only-if-cached'
                                        }}

                                    />

                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.headerContentStyle}>

                                    <Text style={{ color: '#B2B2B2' }}>
                                        {moment(item.date).format('dddd, Do MMMM YYYY')}</Text>
                                    <Text
                                        numberOfLines={3}
                                        style={styles.headerTextStyle}
                                    >
                                        {item.title.rendered}

                                    </Text>


                                </View>

                            </CardSection>

                        </Card>

                       )}


                    keyExtractor={i => i.id}
                   onEndReached={this.reloadContent.bind(this)}

                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
                />

               {this.displaySpinner()}
            </View>


        );
    }


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    headerContentStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        flex: 1

    },
    headerTextStyle: {
        textAlign: 'justify',

        fontSize: 18,
        color: 'black',
        marginRight: 15
    },
    thumbnailStyle: {
        height: 70,
        width: 70
    },
    thumbnailContainerStyle: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10
    },
    imageStyle: {
        height: 300,
        flex: 1,
        width: null
    },


});

export default ArticleList;
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you should always avoid rendering a view/component directly in the `renderItem = { }` prop of your FlatList. Always send a function that is bounded to your current context that returns a component `renderItem = {this._renderItem.bind(this)}` or `renderItem = {() => renderItem()}`. This is not an issue but a usual practice that keeps the code clean and professional. Just a suggestion since you mentioned you're new to RN.

Coming to your question, the spinner shall show up once you wrap your Spinner inside a View component. You can do this either by wrapping your function call `<View> {this.displaySpinner()} </View>` or return a component that is already wrapped in a View `<View> <Spinner/> </View>`.
To make this even more effective, wrap everything including your flatlist but excluding your Header if you have one (Obviously) inside a View and give it a style of flex `flex: 1` with a direction of column `'flexDirection: 'column'`. Now you can justify your content with `justifyContent: 'space-around'` or `'space-between'` whichever works for you.

Final point I'd like to make is again a suggestion. I've been working on RN for a while now but I still find designing the UI one of the most tedious tasks. Hot Reloading helps but not much. To track your UI changes on the screen, you can give the style `borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 1` to your views. This will help you a lot. It sure helps me.

I hope this helps.
Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that spinner in a view like  View style = {{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, width: '100%'}}
        {this.displaySpinner()}
  Close View